# MFC Visual C++ code to check for valid number entries

Tags: c#, c++, validation, mfc

I have this MFC app with the following piece of code to check for the validity of numbers entered using a edit control in the app. Its validated as a string of chars.

```
bool invalid = FALSE;
int string_length = InputEdit.GetWindowText(text, 10);
if (text[0] == '-1')
    for(i=1; i<string_length; i++)
        if((text[i] < '0' || text[i] > '9' ) && text[i] != '.'){
            MessageBeep(MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
            Reactive_Const_Status_Text.SetWindowText("Invalid AA Value");
            invalid = TRUE;
        }
else
    for(i=0; i<string_length; i++)
        if((text[i] < '0' || text[i] > '9' ) && text[i] != '.'){
            MessageBeep(MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
            Reactive_Const_Status_Text.SetWindowText("Invalid AA Value");
            invalid = TRUE;
        }

if(!invalid){   
    double temp_value = atof(text);
    reac.VelAA  = temp_value;
}
```

So this edit control allows users to enter negative numbers. However can someone please shed some light about what this line "if (text[0] == '-1')" does in the code ? Is it checking for negative numbers and if so why does it use '-1' ? Secondly, I'm wanting to convert this code to C# and so how can I convert this line ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the class of InputEdit? Is there a GetWindowText overload? This code seems wrong to me.

Comment: The code is an ugly workaround for the fact that `atof` can't signal a parse error. `strtod` can, and that makes the code far more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, this code is also checking for negative numbers. The first for loop checks from second digit onwards.

The line if (text[0] == '-1') is supposed to be if (text[0] == '-')

I guessed it this way because in C++ single quotes can be used only for single character and not for a string with more than one character.

In C# the same line if (text[0] == '-') will work.

Thanks.

Comment: Your guess is almost right: in C++, the value of a char-literal with multiple characters is unspecified. Your compiler made `'-1'` equal to `'-'`, but it could equally well have chosen `'1'`, `'\0'` or `'-'+'1'`.